# How to connect a rectifier circuit (mains driven) with switching regulator MC34063?

Tags: mc34063

I am  designing a switch mode power supply (44 VDC, 0.56 A, 24.5 W) for my passive PoE. I am using 220/24 VAC transformer + Schottky bridge rectifier (MBRS360) +Pi filter producing 32 V (30-33 V, 0.5 A), which works fine.

Here is simulation result using LTspice:-

[image: Rectifier Circuit]

[image: Simulation]

Now the second circuit is based on MC34063 switching regulator which has to get power from  circuit 1 (previous circuit/Mains driven). It will get 30 Vmin then has to step-up it up to 44 V, 0.56 A. This circuit is also fine when using independent DC source (30VDC). Here is circuit and simulation:-

[image: MC34063 circuit]

[image: Simulation]

Both circuits results fine individually. But when I connect both circuits, I am expecting Vout=44 VDC but I get unexpected wrong results (getting some negative mV). Here is final circuit and simulation.

[image: Final circuit]

[image: Simulation]

Kindly suggest an effective solution.

Comment: Where is point 12 at the last simulation ?

Comment: Point 12 is C6 capictor node, which is Vout ,indeed. And i have to achieve VDC=44volts across it while drawing 0.5A.

Answer (score 1):

First, your rectifier circuit is wrong because you're grounding `D4` at both ends. You only need to ground one side, the other would be "floating". Since there is no such thing in SPICE in general (every node must have a connection to ground), add a `1g` resistor across the ground and "floating" ground.

Second, your second circuit already has a DC source which supplies it constantly, from the beginning. The rectifier would be outputting a rectified sine, therefore the voltage at its output needs time to build up. You could try to cheat by making the input source a cosine and imposing initial voltages on the capacitors. Don't forget about the input transformer, though...

And third, your joined schematic uses the wrong rectifier circuit where `D4` is still shorted.

No comments in rest, but if you correct these you should be able to simulate it. One note, though: if you open up some of the jigs in LTspice, you'll see that, for example, instead of using a full 50Hz, or 60Hz input source, Mike uses a 500Hz or 600Hz, and reduces the feedback and accompanying circuitry, accordingly, in order to not wat for a full 16.67ms or 20ms cycle.